# how to query a limited set of records with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, limit, where-clause

This has been driving me crazy for the last couple of hours as I'm sure there must be a simple solution. Let's say I have the following models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
end
```

And the Comment model has an attribute called Flagged. Assume the post has ten comments and the first two and last two have been marked as flagged.

I want to get a count of how many of the first 5 comments of a post have been flagged. In this case I would want to return 2. So at first I tried:

```
post.comments.limit(5).where(comments: { flagged: true }).count
```

But this returns 4 which makes sense because it's finding the first 5 records where flagged is true. My question is, how can I do the count on only the limited resultset? I tried:

```
first_five_comments = post.comments.limit(5)
first_five_comments.where(flagged: true).count
```

This also returns 4 as it's just chaining the relations together and executing the same query as above.

I know I could do this with a straight SQL statement, but it just seems like there should be a more Rails way to do it. Do I have to add a .all to the above statement and then do the count within the returned array? Obviously this doesn't work:

```
first_five_comments = post.comments.limit(5).all
first_five_comments.where(flagged: true).count
```

because I can't use "where" on an array. If I do have to do it like this, how would I search within the array the get the count?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just a comment, but you are saying "first 2" and "last 2" but your query doesn't have any ordering so saying first/last doesn't really make sense.

Comment: sorry, forgot to add the order clause in what I have been trying, I have ".order(:id)" in there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter the array and then count it's elements.

```
post.comments.limit(5).select{ |comment| comment.flagged? }.size
```

Or shorter:

```
post.comments.limit(5).select(&:flagged?).size
```

Note: `select` is a method of Array, it does not have anything to do with SQL Select statement.

Comment: thanks, i was able to get the top one to work, I'll mark this as the answer seeing as there have been no other responses. I thought there would have been a way to do it within a Relation instead of having to do it through an array.